# add 6x taxes price for a 6-month-product-subscription

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, delivery

We have gift/subscription where you pay once and get "the bear of the month"
delivered once each month.

It is currently configured as a single product (with a average price),
but the problem is the Delivery tax is added just once on checkout...

Is there a way to add delivery tax multiplier or some way to configure the product such that they get 6x taxes in the checkout ?

(we can not simple include the delivery price in the total because, based on the location the delivery tax may be from 0$ to 30$)

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, you can use specific tax rule for a product. And use specific tax rate for this. All needed options are under Admin->Sales->Tax menu. You need to setup tax rate for 600% and implement tax rule with this tax rate. After this you can add tax rule to the needed product.